# Is there a way of deleting the check boxes in column E & F when there is no phone number in column D

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi everyone any you tell me please in the attached document is there a way of deleting the check boxes in column E & F when there is no phone number in column D. I hunted online and all I could find was a script that deletes entire rows - I got it to work but its not what I need.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kZVMYS9El1r6QEnhO0rh_otXFrXBSYetcw8phwaPTdk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: About `deleting the check boxes` of `Is there a way of deleting the check boxes in column E & F when there is no phone number in column D`, in your goal, you want to delete the checkboxes instead of uncheck the checkboxes? And, about `I hunted online and all I could find was a script that deletes entire rows - I got it to work but its not what I need.`, can you provide your current script?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Tanaike.Just to clarify they only ring the phone numbers so I only need a check box in front of the number I do not need a check box where there is no  phone number present I dont mind if its still visible once clicked

Comment: t doest work this is it here function deleteRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[0] == 'delete' || row[0] == '') { // This searches all cells in columns A (change to row[1] for columns B and so on) and deletes row if cell is empty or has value 'delete'.
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
};

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I would like to confirm whether my understanding for your goal is correct. You want to delete the checkboxes of the columns "E" and "F" when the phone number is not put to the column "C". In this case, you don't want to uncheck the checkboxes. You want to delete the checkboxes. Is my understanding correct? When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, the column "D" has the phone number of number and hyphen and the value of "PHONE NUMBER". How do you want to do for the row with the value of "PHONE NUMBER"?

Comment: By the way, I think that when the script is put to the comment, the readability is low. When you show your script, can you add it to your question?

Comment: the above code deletes entire row if b is empty

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: yes that's correct thank you I want to delete the entire check box when there is no phone number in column d   actually there will be a string of numbers  a phone number  like 07 308 9151 I tried the code I posted and it doesnt delete check boxes just unchecks. I didn't give it extensive checks because it doesnt do what I want.

Comment: here is the code again function deleteRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[0] >1 || row[0] == '') { // This searches all cells in columns A (change to row[1] for columns B and so on) and deletes row if cell is empty or has value 'delete'.
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
};

Comment: thank you Tanaike I appreciate your help  Thank you - sorry where do I find sample script

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I proposed a sample script in my answer. Can you see my answer? For example, when you reload your this question on your browser, can you see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to delete the checkboxes of the columns "E" and "F" when the phone number is not put to the column "C".

  - In this case, you don't want to uncheck the checkboxes. You want to delete the checkboxes.
- When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, the column "D" has the phone number of number and hyphen and the value of "PHONE NUMBER". In this answer, I understood that you wanted to delete the checkboxes of columns "E" and "F" for both values.

In order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose to delete the checkboxes using the range list. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const ranges = sheet
    .getRange("D25:D" + sheet.getLastRow())
    .getDisplayValues()
    .reduce((ar, [d], i) => {
      if (d == "") ar.push(`E${i + 25}:F${i + 25}`);
      return ar;
    }, []);
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).removeCheckboxes();
}
```

- When you run above script, the checkboxes at the columns "E" and "F" are deleted when the column "D" has the phone number of number and hyphen and the value of "PHONE NUMBER".
- For example, when you want to uncheck the checkboxes using above script, please use `sheet.getRangeList(ranges).uncheck()` instead of `sheet.getRangeList(ranges).removeCheckboxes()`.

#### References:

- [removeCheckboxes() of Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#removeCheckboxes())
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: sure Tanaike I will be happy to - but where is the button ?

Comment: ok I just found it Thanks again fgor being so helpful - Take care

Comment: @Mark Zangel Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.